# Logs Utility Applications

Tags: filter, logging

I have complex log files, which are full of noise.

Can someone recommand a simple utility program which I can use to define lines which I want to filter out, or highlight using wildcards or any other method?

As well, a utility that can find logs which fulfill a certain condition (e.g., contains a line of a certain template) among a directory full of logs?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) from Microsoft. It has a SQL-like query language to allow you to filter log files based on conditions. Jeff Atwood has a brief overview of it [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000369.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's always good old "grep".

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Bear tail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) with great success. They have a free as well as a paid version.

Comment: You mean Bare Tail. Yeah, it is a great utility.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bit of time to play with PERL and regular expressions, this is the kind of thing they do beautifully.